# NSManagedObjectContext cancel operation while in performBlockAndWait

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

how to cancel an ongoing NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait process? is there anyway to do that.
i want to cancel in case the user gets deleted and do not want to save 1000 entries.

```
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *childError = nil;
        if ([context save:&childError])
        {
            [context.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
                NSError *parentError = nil;
                if ([context.parentContext save:&parentError])
                {
                    // something here
                }
                else
                {
                    // error
                }
            }];
        }
        else
        {
            // error
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Do you have some kind of a loop in the `performBlockAndWait`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't cancel `performBlockAndWait`, there is no API support for this.

The call runs until the block you provide completes. If you need to exit early for some reason, you would need to check a flag from within the block and stop working if the flag said it was time to exit. You can't force it to stop from the outside; you need to finish up and exit from the inside. If that doesn't work with your current calls to `performBlockAndWait`, you can either refactor that code so that it's possible or else live with the current situation.